# What exactly is the specific heat of a gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, gas

When I read that specific heat of Steam $(100 °C)$ is $2010 J/kg \cdot °C$ what exactly am I reading?
What does specific heat of a gas essentially mean when it is not mentioned whether it was measured in constant pressure or constant volume imply?

Also if it implicitly assumes that it was measured in constant pressure $(C_p)$ or volume $(C_v)$ then does it imply the average of $C_p$ or $C_v$ since I heard these quantities depend on temperature?

Comment: It's 2010  J/kg not 2010 J/kg $^{o}C$ and it's the latent heat of vaporization of water, not specific heat

Comment: @BobD, The latent heat of vaporization for water is $ 22.6 × 10^5 J/kg$. The values may vary depending on the sources.

Comment: @BobD, I bet you have my answers. My knowledge is small about thermodynamics so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: yes it does vary.  The number I got from The Engineering Toolbox website  point is it’s not specific heat

Comment: Usually if it's not specified it is $c_p$

Answer (score 0):

specific heat is the quantity of heat required to raise the temperature of one gram of a substance by one Celsius degree and there is a pressure dependence. Please see

[Does specific heat change with pressure? If so, why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100044/does-specific-heat-change-with-pressure-if-so-why)

Hope this was helpful